# LDAP authentication fails

Tags: ldap, authentication, openldap, users, pam

I try to set up an LDAP directory that will allow me to authenticate Debian users. Once the configuration of the LDAP server and PAM files is done, the authentication fails. I think the client doesn't find the ldap user into the directory. When I try to login with an ldap user it says bad login, and when I try to login with a local users it asks me a password, and then the LDAP password.

**Server**

1) I first installed ldap-utils libldap-2.4-2 libldap-2.4-2-dbg slapd slapd-dbg

2) In the file /etc/ldap/ldap.conf :

```
BASE dc=example,dc=com    

URI ldap://192.168.1.254/
```

3)

```
dpkg-reconfigure slapd
```

I check that the informations about the domain are right : correct.

4)

```
ldapsearch -x
```

It fits with what I chose before.

5) I create the .ldif files for the directory and the users

structure.ldif :

```
dn: ou=users,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: organizationalUnit
u: users
description: users

dn: ou=computers,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: organizationalUnit
ou: computers
description: computers

dn: ou=sale,ou=users,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: organizationalUnit
ou: sale
description: sale

dn: ou=direction,ou=users,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: organizationalUnit
ou: direction
description: direction

dn: cn=sale,ou=sale,ou=users,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: posixGroup
gidNumber: 501
cn: sale
description: Sale group

dn: cn=direction,ou=direction,ou=users,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: posixGroup
gidNumber: 502
cn: direction
description: Direction group

dn: cn=pauldupont,cn=direction,ou=direction,ou=users,dc=newsoft,dc=ch
cn=pauldupont,cn=direction,ou=direction,ou=users,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: posixAccount
uid: pauldupont
userPassword: pauldupont
cn: pauldupont
uidnumber: 1050
gidnumber: 501
homeDirectory: /home/profils/pauldupont
sn: pauldupont
```

adduseringroup.ldif :

```
dc: cn=sale,ou=sale,ou=users,dc=example,dc=com
changetype: modify
add: memberuid
memberuid: uid=pauldupont,cn=direction,ou=direction,ou=users,dc=example,dc=com
```

6) I send the files into the directory :

```
ldapadd -x -D "cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com" -W -f file.ldif
```

6)

```
ldapsearch -x
```

The informations are there.

**Client**

1) I installed ldap-utils libldap-2.4-2 libldap-2.4-2-dbg slapd slapd-dbg libnss-ldap libpam-ldap libpam-modules libpam-cracklib nscd

2) libnss-ldap configuration : server ip : 192.168.1.254, dc=example,dc=com

3) libpam-ldap configuration : no that the LDAP admin is like local user, no that the LDAP server asks for informations before making queries

4) 
    dpkg-reconfigure libnss-ldap

The informations are correct.

5) In the file /etc/ldap/ldap.conf

```
BASE dc=example,dc=com
URI ldap://192.168.1.254/
```

6) In the file /etc/nsswitch.conf

```
passwd: compat ldap
group: compat ldap
shadow: compat ldap
```

7) In the file /etc/libnss-ldap.conf

```
base dc=example,dc=com
uri ldap://192.168.1.254/
ldap_version 3
rootbinddn cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com
```

8) In the file /etc/libnss-ldap.secret

```
 ldap password
```

9) In the file /etc/pam_ldap.conf :

```
base dc=example,dc=com
uri ldap://192.168.1.254/
rootbinddn cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com
port 389
scope sub
bind_timelimit 30
idle_timelimit 3600
pam_filter objectClass=posixAccount
pam_login_attribute uid
```

10) In files /etc/pam.d/common-auth & common-account & common-session I added at the bottom :

```
auth sufficient pam_ldap.so
```

11) In the file /etc/pam.d/common-password I added at the bottom :

```
password sufficient pam_ldap.so use_first_pass
```

12)

```
getent passwd && getent group
```

Only shows local users and groups.

13) The client seems to contact the server :

```
ldapsearch -x -H "ldap://192.168.1.254" -b "dc=example,dc=com" dn
```

gives me back the dn entries

14) 
    getent passwd pauldupont

Gives me back nothing and when I check in /var/log/auth.log :

```
May 12 10:43:36 CLI1-DIR-DEB nscd: nss_ldap: failed to bind to LDAP server ldap:///192.168.1.254/: Invalid credentials
May 12 10:43:36 CLI1-DIR-DEB nscd: nss_ldap: reconnecting to LDAP server...
May 12 10:43:36 CLI1-DIR-DEB nscd: nss_ldap: failed to bind to LDAP server ldap:///192.168.1.254/: Invalid credentials
May 12 10:43:36 CLI1-DIR-DEB nscd: nss_ldap: reconnecting to LDAP server...
May 12 10:43:37 CLI1-DIR-DEB nscd: nss_ldap: failed to bind to LDAP server ldap:///192.168.1.254/: Invalid credentials
May 12 10:43:37 CLI1-DIR-DEB nscd: nss_ldap: could not search LDAP server - Server is unavailable
```

It seems the  credentials are wrong. I checked all the configuration files above and I can't find any mistakes.

Does anybody know where the problem is ?

Thank you for your help.

*I'm using Debian Jessie 8.0 AMD64 for the client and the server*

*uname -a : Linux SRV1-DEB 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt9-3~deb8u1 (2015-04-24) x86_64 GNU/Linux*

*OpenLDAP 2.4*

**EDIT** : Once I added the password in the /etc/ldap.secret file and I do a **getent passwd**, I get the ldap users but I still can't connect.

Once I tried to connect I have this in the log file :

```
May 18 09:09:53 CLI1-DIR-DEB login[904]: pam_mail(login:session): user unknown
May 18 09:09:53 CLI1-DIR-DEB login[904]: pam_loginuid(login:session): error_ log for user-name'pauldupont' does not exist
May 18 09:09:53 CLI1-DIR-DEB login[904]: pam_unix(login:session): session opened for user pauldupont by LOGIN(uid=0)
May 18 09:09:53 CLI1-DIR-DEB login[904]: pam_systemd(login:session): Failed to get user data
May 18 09:09:53 CLI1-DIR-DEB login[904]: pam_systemd(login:session): Failed to get user data
May 18 09:09:53 CLI1-DIR-DEB login[904]: User not known to the underlying authentication module
```

Comment: What do your `access` directives in the slapd configuration look like?

Comment: I will check it out as soon as i can and come back with the answer.

Comment: For now, the default values are set :

`olcAccess: {0}to attrs=userPassword,shadowLastChange by self write by anonymous auth by * none`
`olcAccess: {1}to dn.base="" by * read`
`olcAccess: {2}to * by * read`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're supplying a binddn, but bad credentials for it. Are the contents of `/etc/ldap.secret` and what you put in a the `-W` prompt exactly the same?

---

`rootbinddn` is the binddn used by root on the client machine. It should generally not be the rootdn of the suffix as that would mean that compromise of the machine would also compromise the directory.

---

There are few situation in which using `sssd` over `pam_ldap` and `nss-ldap`/`nss-ldapd` is not the correct choice. This is not one of those. (It has been, in my experience, limited to authenticating non-posix accounts.)

---

There are other things wrong here in dealing with groups RFC2307 vs. RFC2307bis, but you're failing before that. When that becomes your actual problem ask another question.

Comment: `/etc/libnss-ldap.secret` should have the password covered.

Comment: @AndrewB You are correct. I missed that.

Comment: Yes, the content of /etc/ldap.secret is the same as what I put in the `-W` prompt. I will check it out one more time as soon as I can, just to be sure. 

If I really can't make it work I will try out with `sssd` , even if I'm surprised it doesn't work with `pam`.

 `/etc/libnss-ldap.secret` has the right password.

Comment: Yes, I checked and it is the same value.

Comment: I was actually wrong, there were nothing in /etc/ldap.secret ! So I added the password and now if I do `getent passwd` I get also LDAP users. When I try to connect it still fails.

Comment: In the end it works. Indeed I had to add the password in /etc/ldap.secret. Thanks a lot to everybody for your help.